# Do anonymous JavaScript objects take memory?

Tags: javascript

If I have the following code:

```
var a = {a:1,b:2,c:3} ['a']
var b = {a:1,b:2,c:3} ['b']
```

I have created two anonymous JavaScript objects. Do the anonymous JavaScript objects take memory?  Or are they instantly garbage collected?

Comment: Everything takes memory. Then it is released and some time later garbage collected. Garbage collection is dependant upon the implementation (ie javascript engine used in a particular browser) and therefore cannot be guessed. Dont worry about it, just use them as you need them

Comment: That's an implementation detail. I would imagine most modern engines would optimize the object away given that simple example. Do you have a more real-world example in mind?

Comment: @squint *Could* .. not so sure 'do' as it's a pretty rare usage case. (But there are some *impressive* front-end optimizations).

Comment: Regarding your "update":  the code you posted is JavaScript, *not* JSON.  It's unclear why you rolled back the edit that changed it to say JavaScript.

Comment: @squint, instead of using switch case statements, I'd like to use cleaner code.

Comment: @wyzard, thanks, but I specifically wanted to talk about the JSON object. Js objects could also be strings and numbers. I didn't change it back.

Comment: But it's not JSON, it's a JavaScript object.  JSON is a text format for data serialization:  if you'd written `JSON.parse("{a:1,b:2,c:3}")` then you'd be using JSON (as a way to *create* a JavaScript object).  The string is JSON; the object produced by parsing it — or in this case, the object literal that you've written directly in your source code without parsing from JSON — is a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: @user139301: I'd just go ahead and use whatever you feel is cleaner. Again, I'm pretty sure modern engines will optimize the object creation away. Even if they don't, it would probably only make a difference if the object is very large and the code is run over and over rapidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the anonymous objects has to exist while it's being used for the property lookup, so it takes memory during that time.  After the property lookup is finished, there's nothing using the object anymore, so it becomes garbage.

There's no guarantee as to when the garbage will actually be *collected*, so it's possible (and likely) that the objects still exist in memory after those lines have run.  But they're *eligible* for garbage collection, and will be collected at some point in the future when the JavaScript engine needs to free up memory for other data.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how garbage collection works, that is similar to your question, you will note that o2.a is similar to your scenario.  It is also noted that since a part of the object is still in use, the entire variable is still in use.

```
var o = { 
  a: {
    b:2
  }
}; 
// 2 objects are created. One is referenced by the other as one of its property.
// The other is referenced by virtue of being assigned to the 'o' variable.
// Obviously, none can be garbage-collected


var o2 = o; // the 'o2' variable is the second thing that 
            // has a reference to the object
o = 1;      // now, the object that was originally in 'o' has a unique reference
            // embodied by the 'o2' variable

var oa = o2.a; // reference to 'a' property of the object.
               // This object has now 2 references: one as a property, 
               // the other as the 'oa' variable

o2 = "yo"; // The object that was originally in 'o' has now zero
           // references to it. It can be garbage-collected.
           // However what was its 'a' property is still referenced by 
           // the 'oa' variable, so it cannot be free'd

oa = null; // what was the 'a' property of the object originally in o 
           // has zero references to it. It can be garbage collected.
```

So in general, I would say, yes they still take up memory.

However, I also suspect that many browsers would be smart enough to figure out that you have only created the object on that line, and assigned just a part of it, so there would be no reason to keep the entire object, and may delete it.  But in general that memory is being used as long as the a or b variable is around.

Answer (score 0):

The expression "anonymous JavaScript object" is a little odd. JavaScript objects are just objects and have no names in and of themselves. They may or not be referred to by other things, including but not limited to variables to which they were assigned. For example, consider the following case:

```
function make_getter(obj) { return function(p) { return obj[p]; }; }

var getter = make_getter({a: 1});
```

Here `{a: 1}` is "anonymous", yet it is referred to, by virtue of being closed over, within the function returned by `make_getter` and assigned to `getter`, As long as `getter` is still in scope, the object thus cannot (and will not) be garbage collected.

Whether or not an object is garbage collected is related to whether is referenced in some live context, not just whether it has been assigned to a variable. it may be assigned to a variable but have gone out of scope; or it may be not assigned to a variable but yet persist in some scope.

As other posts have mentioned, the actual GC happens when and if the engine feels like it, and you don't have, or need, control over it.

To put it differently, the two fragments below are identical in GC terms:

```
function gc1() {
    return {a:1, b:2, c:3}['a'];
}

function gc2() {
    var o = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
    return o['a'];
}
```

Nobody cares whether you happened to have given a name `o` to the object. The question is when it goes out of scope, which in this case happens at the end of the function.